# How to get last record for every username

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a record like below

```
item  | group  | score | updatedate |
------+--------+-------+------------+
item0 | group0 | 900   | 2018-01-01 |
item1 | group0 | 1000  | 2018-01-05 |
item1 | group1 | 1110  | 2018-01-01 |
item2 | group0 | 850   | 2018-01-01 |
item2 | group1 | 755   | 2018-01-02 |
item2 | group2 | 985   | 2018-01-03 |
```

how to get only 1 record per item only with the latest update? the record should like this

```
item  | group  | score | updatedate |
------+--------+-------+------------+
item0 | group0 | 900   | 2018-01-01 |
item1 | group0 | 1000  | 2018-01-05 |
item2 | group2 | 985   | 2018-01-03 |
```

it is SQL Server 2012, I've tried with this query

```
SELECT a.item, a.updateddate, a.score
FROM pricelist a
LEFT OUTER JOIN pricelist b ON a.item = b.item AND a.UpdateDate < b.updateddate
WHERE b.item IS NULL
ORDER BY a.item desc;
```

but still show duplicate item

Comment: Have you tried anything so far at all? What was the SQL you used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of answers to this one. One is to use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       item,
       [group],
       score,
       updatedate
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY updatedate DESC);
```

Otherwise, you can use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT item,
           [group],
           score,
           updatedate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY updatedate DESC) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT item,
       [group],
       score,
       updatedate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT item, [group], score, updatedate
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY updatedate DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY item;
```

Notes: *Don't* name your columns (or tables, etc.) using reserved SQL keywords like `GROUP`.  I had to escape your `[group]` column to make the query work.  Also, if you could have a single item with more than one record tied for having the most recent `updatedate`, and you want to include all ties, then we can try replacing `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help you.

```
SELECT 
    T.item
    ,T.[group]
    ,T.score
    ,T.updateddate
FROM 
#ItemTbl T 
inner join 
(
select 
    item
    ,MAX(updateddate) updateddate
FROM #ItemTbl
group by 
    item) T2 ON T.item=T2.item and t.updateddate=t2.updateddate
```